# Safari ignore CSS :not() rule

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I got the problem with ***Safari 13.0.5 (14608.5.12)***

[image: About safari information]

Trying to modify some of the [WordPress Divi builder plugin](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) styles, I came across an unexpected problem with the inability to apply a negative rule that would prevent the plugin from styling if necessary in a particular place.

**Modifying file:**

> src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/divi-builder/includes/builder/styles/frontend-builder-plugin-style.min.css

**So I came from this:**

```css
#et-boc .et-l .hentry,
#et-boc .et-l a,
#et-boc .et-l a:active,
#et-boc .et-l blockquote,
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message,.star-rating),
#et-boc .et-l em,
#et-boc .et-l form,
#et-boc .et-l h1,
#et-boc .et-l h2,
#et-boc .et-l h3,
#et-boc .et-l h4,
#et-boc .et-l h5,
#et-boc .et-l h6,
#et-boc .et-l hr,
#et-boc .et-l iframe,
#et-boc .et-l img,
#et-boc .et-l input,
#et-boc .et-l label,
#et-boc .et-l li,
#et-boc .et-l object,
#et-boc .et-l ol,
#et-boc .et-l p,
#et-boc .et-l span,
#et-boc .et-l strong,
#et-boc .et-l textarea,
#et-boc .et-l ul,
#et-boc .et-l video {background: 0 0;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: inherit;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: inherit;
    text-shadow: inherit;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

**To this:**

```css
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) .hentry,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) a,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) a:active,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) blockquote,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) div:not(.woocommerce-message,.star-rating),
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) em,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) form,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h1,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h2,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h3,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h4,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h5,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) h6,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) hr,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) iframe,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) img,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) input,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) label,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) li,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) object,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) ol,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) p,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) span,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) strong,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) textarea,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) ul,
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) video {background: 0 0;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: inherit;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: inherit;
    text-shadow: inherit;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

This solution works fine at Chrome, Firefox, etc!
...except Safari =/

[image]

What's the problemm with this browser?

Comment: This was a very well framed question! I wish this was the norm, not the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, it is better to avoid such complex code in styles and not stumble on browser bugs. I did not manage to find out why Safari behaves in this way, however, with regard to the [DIVI plug-in](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/), such a solution would complicate the code even more. I am sure that in future versions the bug will be fixed.

However I found another simple solution: since [DIVI plugin](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) is quite aggressive to any code placed in it, then a simple way out was to put the applications and the necessary parts of the code that fall into the stream into an iframe that completely isolates the code you need from third-party interference.

For example you can do so:

**interest.pug**

```
extends index
block content
    .interest
        .container.container--content.interest__container
            script.
                function interestIframeOnLoad () {
                    var interestIframe = document.getElementById('interest__iframe')
                    interestIframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
                        selector: '#interest',
                        //...your_app_init_options_here
                    }, '*')
                }

            iframe(
                src='./interest__iframe.pug'
                class='interest__iframe'
                id='interest__iframe'
                frameborder='0'
                onload='javascript: interestIframeOnLoad()'
            )
```

**interest__iframe.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        title Interest inner app
        script(src='../../assets/js/interest.js')

    body
        #interest
        script.
            let appWasLaunched = false;
            const iframe = window.top.document.getElementById('interest__iframe');

            function launchApp(options) {
                window.app.interest(options);
            }

            window.addEventListener('message', e => {
                if (!appWasLaunched) {
                    appWasLaunched = true;
                    var data = e.data;
                    launchApp(data);
                }
            }, false);
```

**interest.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export default function interest (options) {
    new Vue({
        data: options,
        render: (h) => h(App)
    }).$mount(options.selector);
}

window.app = window.app || {};
window.app.interest = interest;
```

The code above uses the [parsel bundler](https://parceljs.org/) Therefore, you can use the `.pag` extension in the iframe `src` attribute and you can even use `.scss` and **ES6** inside that iframe which basically closed the problem with the [DIVI plugin](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) in my case. I hope my answer will be useful to someone

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a list of selectors in `:not()` for all browsers yet, which is why you don't see this work in Safari — the whole selector list gets dropped. See [MDN's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

You need to split this into two `:not()`s:

```css
...
#et-boc .et-l *:not(.no-divi-styles) div:not(.woocommerce-message):not(.star-rating),
...
```

Comment: Well noticed. It seems the plugin developers used `:not(.selector1, selector2)`  the capabilities of CSS4 which is not yet supported

Comment: The example described above seems cumbersome but unfortunately a simple rule `*:not(.selector)` does not apply to *Safari* browser